# SQL string formatter

Tags: sql, linux, formatting, code-formatting

Is there a program, a utility, or some programmatic library, preferably for Linux, that takes an unformatted SQL string and pretty prints it?

For example, I would like the following

```
select * from users where name = 'Paul'
```

be changed to something like this

```
select *
from users
where
   name = 'Paul'
```

The exact formatting is not important.
I just need something to take a large SQL string and break it up into something more readable.

Comment: This [SQL Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cymonk.sql-formatter) plugin is working great in vscode.
You can use the [sql-formatter cli version](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/sql-formatter#usage-from-command-line) of the node package as well.

Comment: Related: [Command line SQL formatter or beautifier - Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/85348/command-line-sql-formatter-or-beautifier)

Comment: Related: *[What free SQL formatting tools exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310188/what-free-sql-formatting-tools-exist)*

Answer (score 86):

#### Try sqlparse module's sqlformat

Check out [sqlparse](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse). It is a Python module that installs the command `sqlformat`. Usage is simple, e.g.:

```
sqlformat --reindent --keywords upper --identifiers lower my_file.sql
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo "sElECt f1,f2,fname,lName FrOm tblName WhErE f1=true aNd fname iS nOt null oRdEr bY lName aSc" | \
sqlformat - --reindent --keywords upper --use_space_around_operators
SELECT f1,
       f2,
       fname,
       lName
FROM tblName
WHERE f1 = TRUE
  AND fname IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY lName ASC
```

I tried the aforementioned CLI alternatives, but:

- `sqlinform` is out, because I want an open source CLI application.
- `fsqlf` has only few features (`create view` is missing for example).

##### Note on SQL keywords

There are many SQL keywords. And they differ by SQL dialect. Wikipedia has a list: *[List of SQL reserved words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words)*

These keywords are illegal for use as an identifier. And if you still try, then there might be unpleasant surprises.

Thanks to `sqlformat` I learned that "REF" is a [reserved keyword in SQL:2011 and SQL:2008](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

So this explains why when you say want uppercase keywords but lowercase identifiers "rEf" here becomes "REF", but "mYrEf" becomes "myref":

```
$ echo 'sElEcT rEf fRoM mYtAbLe' | sqlformat - --reindent --keywords upper --identifiers lower
SELECT REF
FROM mytable


$ echo 'sElEcT mYrEf fRoM mYtAbLe' | sqlformat - --reindent --keywords upper --identifiers lower
SELECT myref
FROM mytable
```

Comment: This totally botched the formatting (of indentation) i wanted, no matter the arguments supplied.

Comment: Same.  Even with just -r, incidentally only after the `ORDER BY` clause, it started incrementally indenting by almost 40 characters for each new line of field provided.

Comment: This tool is automatically installed by [Apache Superset](https://superset.apache.org/).  And I consider it as some form of endorsement from Superset.

Comment: It doesn't seem to support pipe `|` for reading data from `STDIN`.

Comment: Just use `>` to redirect output to a file.

Comment: @cprn You can in version 0.1.2 ---
"Format FILE according to OPTIONS. Use "-" as FILE to read from stdin."

Comment: sqlformat@0.2.4 ist only getting `Killed` somehow when try to run it over my sql file.

Comment: I hope you don't have more than a few records as I quit waiting for output after minutes.

Comment: If you use the programs sqlformat and the npm installed sql-formatter-cli in sequence in that order, the SQL formatted output is exquisite.

Comment: I probably won't write my grandparents to tell them about how great this formatter is, but it was good enough for my task...

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The indent is in a mess. I try this:
CREATE TABLE student (
sid INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(16), login VARCHAR(32) UNIQUE, age SMALLINT, gpa FLOAT );
sqlformat tmp.sql  --reindent --indent_width 4 --keywords upper --use_space_around_operators
The result is:
CREATE TABLE student (sid INT PRIMARY KEY,
                                      name VARCHAR(16),
                                           login VARCHAR(32) UNIQUE,
                                                             age SMALLINT, gpa FLOAT);

Comment: The easiest way to install this is to run: `pipx install sqlparse`

Answer (score 16):

#### Try fsqlf

[fsqlf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fsqlf/) is a command line or GUI program, open source, to format SQL.  It supports having a *formatting.conf* file which allows you a lot of flexibility in how the final product looks.

Example 1:

```
☺  [wwalker@speedy:~]
$ echo "select f1, f2, fname, lName from tblName where f1 = true and fname is not null order by lName asc" | fsqlf

SELECT
  f1
, f2
, fname
, lName
FROM tblName
WHERE f1=true
AND fname is not null
ORDER BY lName asc
```

Example 2:

```
☺  [wwalker@speedy:~]
$ vim formatting.conf # 2 character change

☺  [wwalker@speedy:~]
$ echo "select f1, f2, fname, lName from tblName where f1 = true and fname is not null order by lName asc" | fsqlf

SELECT
 f1 ,
 f2 ,
 fname ,
 lName
FROM tblName
WHERE f1=true
AND fname is not null
ORDER BY lName asc
```

Example 3:

```
☺  [wwalker@speedy:~]
$ vim formatting.conf # 1 character change

☺  [wwalker@speedy:~]
$ echo "select f1, f2, fname, lName from tblName where f1 = true and fname is not null order by lName asc" | fsqlf

SELECT
 f1 , f2 , fname , lName
FROM tblName
WHERE f1=true
AND fname is not null
ORDER BY lName asc
```

Comment: This is the best answer! Because you can format SQL queries on your own machine with an open source tool without having to use a third party website or a proprietary tool! With shady data retention and privacy policies!

Comment: Any PPA for easy install on Ubuntu-like?