# What free SQL formatting tools exist?

Tags: sql, formatting

I want to beautify the SQL queries I write.

What free tools exist that allow for SQL query formatting?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627643/sql-formatting-tool

Comment: Related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11074/sql-query-formatter

Comment: Try [ApexSQL Refactor](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.aspx). It integrates into SSMS and had 150+ formatting options. Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL.

Comment: There is now a free online SQL Formatter  http://sqlinform.com/sql_formatter_online.html

Comment: Related: [Command line SQL formatter or beautifier - Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/85348/command-line-sql-formatter-or-beautifier)

Answer (score 58):

[PoorMansTSqlFormatter](https://github.com/TaoK/PoorMansTSqlFormatter) is a free and open-source online beautifier, with offline an [SSMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) Add-In, command-line beautifier tool, and [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) plugin.

The project aims to format any T-SQL (2000 or later) script, no matter the length or complexity.

Comment: I am glad I found you! I was looking for something that is FREE, does not 'call home' (online) to watch my queries,  is portable and uses my 'feel-home' environment of Notepad++. Thanks heaps!

Comment: there is also a free online Java based formatter http://www.sqlinform.com

Comment: @SarjanWebDev, Why would *any* app call home to watch your queries? That seems totally malicious.

Comment: I used it's notepad++ plugin, and it seems to do the trick. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I did this: 1. Notepad++ > Plugins menu > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager > Available tab > Poor Man's T-Sql Formatter > Install. 2. Restart Notepad++. 3. Plugins > Poor Man's T-SQL Formatter > Format T-SQL code.

Comment: As of today 1Jun2017, it does not yet work in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio/ SSMS 2016: issue: https://github.com/TaoK/PoorMansTSqlFormatter/issues/144 , previous usage was like: http://blog.dancody.me/post/50954275473/sql-formatter-for-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: As of today, July 8, it looks like it will work: https://github.com/TaoK/PoorMansTSqlFormatter/issues/161#issuecomment-313715039

Comment: @ManoharReddyPoreddy: No, that issue was about the site being down. Recent versions of SSMS (and VS) are still not supported - but I'm working on it.

Comment: great, looking forward to it. Ideally, everyone should be able to contribute to your beautiful tool, so divide into smaller tasks, and ask for small help. I will certainly help. best of luck.

Answer (score 17):

**[T-SQL Tidy](http://www.tsqltidy.com)** (dead link) was a very good online SQL formatter/beautifier.

It had a lot of formatting options. Although it was targeted at T-SQL, it should have worked with most SQL dialects.

Comment: It now offers an SSMS add-in that works completely offline. Seems to offer more options than PoorMansTsqlFormatter.

Comment: link seems to be broken now. can't seem to find it on the web anymore.

Answer (score 6):

There is a free online [Instant SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm).  The site also sells some other versions (add-in for Visual Studio, for example), but the online version is free.

Answer (score 2):

Re [Christoph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310188/what-free-sql-formatting-tools-exist/3310435#3310435):

I was looking for the same in [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) and found a link that gives an idea of how to create your own formatting with macros: *[Formatting SQL in Notepad++](http://peoplesoft.wikidot.com/formatting-sql-in-notepad)*

It seems like it would work, but I'm going to use one of the [SSMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) Add-ins in the previous answer (less work).

Comment: The gist is using a few (simple) regular expressions to transform a presumed format (single-line SQL, etc.) to another format. It could also be done by a script (e.g., in Perl or Python). It will work in a particular circumstance, but it is not generally applicable.

Answer (score 1):

I've always been a fan of [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com).

Their lite version is free, but it still comes with [the SQL Beautifier](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_premium/premium_feature.html).

As an added bonus, occasionally you'll find some chinglish hiding in odd places.

Comment: The Lite version no longer includes the SQL Beautifier for free -- it requires you to purchase to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

[Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) if using OS X.

Otherwise, just work out what you need, and then develop your query using your knowledge and use the command line tool (my personal favourite:)).

Comment: But Sequel Pro is only for MySQL, right?

Comment: That is correct @newenglander, Sequel Pro only has support for MySQL; however, Postgresql support is in the works!