# Is there an sql reindenter?

Tags: sql

I'm looking to pretty print SQL code. Preferably free and/or online based.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310188/free-sql-formatting-tool/3310518#3310518

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My favorite: http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm?ref=g_wangz

Comment: btw top 1 in Google for "pretty print SQL"

Comment: +1 I use this site to format SQL before posting @ stackoverflow

Comment: @Cybernate +1 for formatting code before posting to stackoverflow :)

Comment: :( for needing to format code before posting on SO. SO is not the only place code needs to be readable, how about in source control?

Comment: That tool did the job perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQLNAV you May have the formatter tools as well.
They can do the job

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this lightweight javascript  plugin

http://www.eslinstructor.net/vkbeautify/

simply grab the code and use it.

With this plugin you can beautify not only SQL, but also XML, JSON and CSS.

Pretty useful.