# Autocapitalize sql keywords in notepad++

Tags: sql, notepad++, keyword, capitalize

Is there a way to make notepad++ automatically make keywords uppercase?  If no, then is there another text editor that does do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6745589/3854195) regarding a Notepad++ plugin for formatting SQL

Poor Man's T-SQL Formatter
https://github.com/TaoK/PoorMansTSqlFormatter

Comment: Wow.  Now that is some pretty code!  Wish I found this tool a long time ago.

Comment: Great to have especially when you are working on other people's code!  ;-)

Comment: Well, I guess its a good thing I found it BEFORE I have ever even had to deal with anyone else's code. I've only been learning SQL for a month or so.  I was actually disappointed with notepad++'s style configurator.  I was thinking it was missing something but looking for plugins never crossed my mind.

Comment: Poor Mans SQL Formatter installs an old version of .net on your computer and then you  discover it's not compatible with the latest version of notepad++ (7.7)

Comment: Don't bother with theSQLinForm notepadd++ plugin either if you just want to uppercase the keywords

Answer (score 4):

Highlight the words and press Ctrl + Shift + U

OR

Edit -> Convert Case To - UpperCase

PS: if you need to select a specific word and change it to uppercase in your whole document, you can always use 'Search n Replace'. For eg: Search for 'keyword', replace all with 'KEYWORD'.