# Can you auto-case a .sql file?

Tags: sql

SQL is case-insenstive for all SQL functions (e.g. `DATE(col_1)` & `date(col_1)` are identical).

But the convention is to use upper case. So `DATE(col_1)` is the convention.

I have not come across a parser or linter that auto-capitalises. Is there a way to take a sql script, and auto capitalise it to convention?

Comment: Google search the terms: `sql formatter` there are many, some online based, others not, but varies depending upon your DB type, and the available functions that can vary between DBs. (and DB versions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Autocapitalize sql keywords in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33028838/autocapitalize-sql-keywords-in-notepad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an online sql formatter may cause information security violations depending on the company. If there is a risk, I recommend using the notepad++ replace all feature, but a little effort is needed.