# Formatting Clear and readable SQL queries

Tags: sql, plsql, code-cleanup

I'm writing some SQL queries with several subqueries and lots of joins everywhere, both inside the subquery and the resulting table from the subquery.

We're not using views so that's out of the question.

After writing it I'm looking at it and scratching my head wondering what it's even doing cause I can't follow it.

What kind of formatting do you use to make an attempt to clean up such a mess? Indents perhaps?

Comment: what platform? There are plugins for SSMS and MySQL Workbench that will "beautify" your SQL code for you.

Comment: Good question. I have yet to find a convincing formatting-rule for SQL myself.

Comment: @Brian Driscoll, which plugings do you know for MySQL Workbench?

Comment: @Brian, I'm using PL/SQL. Are there any stand-alone scripts or tools out there that will beautify the code? Where I could just paste the code and it will give me a beautified version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392001/sql-string-formatter

Comment: best way to make the SQL code more readable is to use standards within your team. There are tools like SQLinForm which support team standards using formatting profiles.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With large queries I tend to rely a lot on named result sets using `WITH`. This allows to define the result set beforehand and it makes the main query simpler. Named results sets may help to make the query plan more efficient as well e.g. postgres stores the result set in a temporary table.

Example:

```
WITH 
  cubed_data AS (
     SELECT 
        dimension1_id,
        dimension2_id,
        dimension3_id,
        measure_id,
        SUM(value) value
     FROM
        source_data
     GROUP BY
        CUBE(dimension1, dimension2, dimension3),
        measure
  ), 
  dimension1_label AS(
     SELECT 
        dimension1_id,
        dimension1_label
     FROM 
        labels 
     WHERE 
        object = 'dimension1'
  ), ...
SELECT 
  *
FROM  
  cubed_data
  JOIN dimension1_label USING (dimension1_id)
  JOIN dimension2_label USING (dimension2_id)
  JOIN dimension3_label USING (dimension3_id)
  JOIN measure_label USING (measure_id)
```

The example is a bit contrived but I hope it shows the increase in clarity compared to inline subqueries. Named result sets have been a great help for me when I've been preparing data for OLAP use. Named results sets are also must if you have/want to create recursive queries.

`WITH` works at least on current versions of Postgres, Oracle and SQL Server

Comment: The WITH keyword is interesting. Definitely makes the code so much cleaner since I can just refer to the result set by name in subsequent lines.

Comment: CTEs are great for improving query readability, but unfortunately, they can obscure errors sometimes and make them harder to debug. If an error occurs in CTE, you'll get an error, that points to your query in general, rather than show where it occurs. If CTEs are nested, that makes it even more difficult to debug.

Answer (score 11):

Boy is this a loaded question. :)  There are as many ways to do it right as there are smart people on this site. That said, here is how I keep myself sane when building complex sql statements:

```
select
    c.customer_id
   ,c.customer_name
   ,o.order_id
   ,o.order_date
   ,o.amount_taxable
   ,od.order_detail_id
   ,p.product_name
   ,pt.product_type_name
from
    customer c
inner join
    order o
    on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
inner join
    order_detail od
    on o.order_id = od.order_id
inner join
    product p
    on od.product_id = p.product_id
inner join
    product_type pt
    on p.product_type_id = pt.product_type_id
where
    o.order_date between '1/1/2011' and '1/5/2011'
and
    (
        pt.product_type_name = 'toys'
     or
        pt.product_type_name like '%kids%'
    )
order by
    o.order_date
   ,pt.product_type_name
   ,p.product_name
```

If you're interested, I can post/send layouts for inserts, updates and deletes as well as correlated subqueries and complex join predicates.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Seems like most people agree with whitespace!

Comment: I like to focus on the atomicity of each line. Using this pattern, I can quickly scan the hierarchy for the node I'm looking for and then drill. The primary drawback to this, in my experience, is that printouts eat paper.  On the positive side, they rarely wrap or bleed off the page.

Comment: What I like about this layout is it is easy to comment out parts of the query when you are trying to find out why it doesn't return the expected results. Always important when writing complex queries.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, people break lines on reserved words, and indent any sub-queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE value in
   (SELECT *
   FROM tablename2 
   WHERE condition)
ORDER BY column
```

Answer (score 4):

Table aliases and simple consistency will get you a long, long way

What looks decent is breaking lines on main keywords SELECT, FROM, WHERE (etc..).

Joins can be trickier, indenting the ON part of joins brings out the important part of it to the front.

Breaking complicated logical expressions (joins and where conditions both) on the same level also helps.

Indenting logically the same level of statement (subqueries, opening brackets, etc)

Capitalize all keywords and standard functions.

Really complex SQL will not shy away from comments - although typically you find these in SQL scripts not dynamic SQL.

**EDIT example:**

```
SELECT a.name, SUM(b.tax)
FROM   db_prefix_registered_users a 
       INNER JOIN db_prefix_transactions b 
           ON a.id = b.user_id
       LEFT JOIN db_countries
           ON b.paid_from_country_id = c.id
WHERE  a.type IN (1, 2, 7) AND
       b.date < (SELECT MAX(date) 
                 FROM audit) AND
       c.country = 'CH'
```

So, at the end to sum it up - consistency matters the most.

Answer (score 4):

In general, I follow a simple hierarchical set of formatting rules.  Basically, keywords such as SELECT, FROM, ORDER BY all go on their own line.  Each field goes on its own line (in a recursive fashion)

```
SELECT 
    F.FIELD1,
    F.FIELD2,
    F.FIELD3
FROM
    FOO F 
WHERE 
    F.FIELD4 IN 
    (
        SELECT 
            B.BAR
        FROM 
            BAR B
        WHERE
            B.TYPE = 4
            AND B.OTHER = 7
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

I like to use something like:

```
SELECT    col1,
          col2,
          ...
FROM
    MyTable as T1
INNER JOIN
    MyOtherTable as T2
        ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
        AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
LEFT JOIN
    (   
        SELECT 1,2,3
        FROM Someothertable
        WHERE somestuff = someotherstuff
    ) as T3
    ON t1.field = t3.field
```

Answer (score 3):

The **only true and right** way to format SQL is:

```
SELECT t.mycolumn        AS column1
      ,t.othercolumn     AS column2
      ,SUM(t.tweedledum) AS column3
FROM   table1 t
      ,(SELECT u.anothercol
              ,u.memaw                  /*this is a comment*/
        FROM   table2       u
              ,anothertable x
        WHERE  u.bla       = :b1        /*the bla value*/
        AND    x.uniquecol = :b2        /*the widget id*/
       ) v
WHERE  t.tweedledee = v.anothercol
AND    t.hohum      = v.memaw
GROUP BY t.mycolumn
        ,t.othercolumn
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
;
```

;)

Seriously though, I like to use WITH clauses (as already suggested) to tame very complicated SQL queries.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a view so it's easier to visualize, maybe keep a screenshot as part of the documentation.  You don't have to save the view or use it for any other purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Indenting certainly but you can also split the subqueries up with comments, make your alias names something really meaningful and specify which subquery they refer to e.g. innerCustomer, outerCustomer.

Common Table Expressions can really help in some cases to break up a query into meaningful sections.

Answer (score 2):

An age-old question with a thousand opinions and no one right answer, and one of my favorites. Here's my two cents.

With regards to subqueries, lately I've found it easier to follow what's going on with "extreme" indenting and adding comments like so:

```
SELECT mt.Col1, mt.Col2, subQ.Dollars
 from MyTable1 mt
  inner join (--  Get the dollar total for each SubCol
              select SubCol, sum(Dollars) Dollars
               from MyTable2
               group by SubCol) subQ
   on subQ.SubCol = mt.Col1
 order by mt.Col2
```

As for the other cent, I only use upper case on the first word. With pages of run-on queries, it makes it a bit easier to pick out when a new one starts.

Your mileage will, of course, vary.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, alot of responses here, but one thing I haven't seen in many is COMMENTS!  I tend to add a lot of comments throughout, especially with large SQL statements.  Formatting is important, but well placed and meaningful *comments* are extremely important, not just for you but the poor soul who needs to maintain the code ;)