# Can I use a table from the WITH clause in the IN clause?

Tags: sql, db2, common-table-expression, readability

In attempt to write more readable SQL code by following [this recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5461747/), I'm trying to use the `WITH` clause.

It works here:

```
WITH
    t AS
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            TABLE1
        WHERE
            COL1 = 'foo'
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM
    t
WHERE
    COL2 > 42
```

But it doesn't work in the following case:

```
WITH
    t AS
    (
        SELECT
            COL1
        FROM
            TABLE1
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TABLE2
WHERE
    COL2 IN t
```

It returns the following error:

> 1) [Code: -206, SQL State: 42703]  "T" is not valid in the context
>   where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.22.29

Just in case it's not clear what I mean by the non-working query above, here is what:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TABLE2
WHERE
    COL2 IN
    (
        SELECT
            COL1
        FROM
            TABLE1
    )
```

How can I use a table for the `WITH` clause in the `IN` clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"T" acts as a table so you have to select a column in order to compare it with "IN"

```
WITH
t AS
(
    SELECT
        COL1
    FROM
        TABLE1
)
SELECT
 *
FROM
TABLE2
WHERE
COL2 IN ( SELECT COL FROM t )
```

Answer (score 1):

`IN` requires a subquery.  You simply need:

```
WHERE COL2 IN (SELECT ? FROM t)
```

Note that you need to specify the column as well as the table.

Comment: But what if my subquery is huge? I'm trying to use the `WITH` clause to increase readability.

Comment: @r_a: then create a second CTE ("with" clause)

Comment: The query behind `t` can be huge. The subquery you'll ned for the `IN` won't be huge, it's just that `SELECT ... FROM t` regardless of the size of the subquery behind `t`. But you'll need that `SELECT` as with any other table, view, etc. used in `IN`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Could you please give an explicit example?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `exists` :

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1 
              from table1 t1
              where t1.COL1 = t2.COL2 and t1.COL1 = <whatever filter>
             );
```