# Formatting SQL code in stdout in terminal

Tags: sql, linux, unix, terminal, format

Is there any unix/linux utility that can format (indent) SQL code from stdin to stdout?
I wasn't able to find any.
I have special logger utility that prints SQL dumps to stdout, but it's hard to read it since it's not formatted.

Comment: This is one reason why log already formatted SQL to the log files :)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change that. It's legacy software and there's no way how to change that.

Comment: There's another thread discussing this kind of tool http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392001/sql-string-formatter